# SQL Server no permite usar REGEX_REPLACE

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, replace

Estoy intentando eliminar determinados caracteres de un String que cumplan una determinada condición.
El problema que estoy teniendo es que no veo una función que me permita hacer esto en `SQL Server`, ya que necesito usar una expresión regular.
He leído varios posts sobre `REGEX` pero no me permite aplicarlo con SQL Server, (si por ejemplo con `PostgreSQL`).

Sabrían decirme si hay alguna función similar para `SQL Server` o alguna manera de poder programar mi expresión regular?

Nota: No me sirve con hacer algo similar a

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET COLUMN =  REPLACE(COLUMN , '''', '')
WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%''@%'
```

Actualizacion:

- En la web encontré esta documentación, donde dice que podría hacerse en el propio WHERE usando LIKE, pero que es menos flexible.
  [Ejemplo sin usar REGEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server)
- Y aquí una guía de uso de expresiones regulares, pero no termina de servirme.
  [Usar expresiones regulares SQL Server](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/es/como-usar-expresiones-regulares-regex-en-sql-server-para-generar-datos-de-prueba-aleatorios/)

Objetivo:

Deseo eliminar las comillas simples de todos los registros que contengan: '@XXXX', donde XXXX puede ser cualquier caracter alfanumérico.
Viendolo mas claro en un ejemplo, deseo transformar el String1 en String2:

`String1`: Tengo este '@string' de '@ejemplo' y quiero 'modificarlo' '@facilmente

`String2`: Tengo este @string de @ejemplo y quiero 'modificarlo' 'facilmente'

Comment: Qué arrojó tu investigación? Es decir, antes de venir aquí seguro lo buscaste en google, o la documentación oficial de sql server. Qué descubriste?

Comment: Cuando dices _eliminar determinados caracteres de un String que cumplan una determinada condición_, cuáles son los caracteres y cuál es la condición?. Quizás en [estas respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server) encuentres algo.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Actualicé el POST con mas información @Japv

Comment: No hay expresiones regulares en SQL server lamentablemente, una posibilidad es no usarlas e intentar resolverlo de otra forma o la otra es armar un assemly por ejemplo en C# e instalarlo en el servidor.

Comment: ¿Son muchas las ocurrencias del patrón `@string` o digamos los posibles patrones de este tipo es un número ya conocido?, si fuera así se podría armar algo con una tabla de sustitución.